# Redmine-GitLab integration doesn't work as expected

Tags: gitlab, redmine

Redmine-GitLab integration described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/redmine.html) somehow doesn't work for me this way. I can't refer to an issue using `#<ID>` or `<PROJECT>-<ID>` - it becomes just plain text.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `#<ID>` working as a link to Redmine issue:

In GitLab go to "Settings->General->Visibility, project features, permissions" and disable "Issues".
Redmine integration in GitLab has to be enabled, of course.

Now it should work as expected: the "plain text" becomes a link.